# Windows 8: Visual Studio 12/13 not working on FAT32

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, ntfs, windows-8.1, fat32

The problem is put as follows:
I installed my VS2013 on a FAT32 disk and it works nice except with windows 8 app development, where the XAML designer just won't open while requesting elevated privilege of running "icacls" commands, of which I approves of course, to modify the permission on the IDE folder to gain access to it, only to fail because it's FAT32 and it just doesn't have any permission mechanism. As a result, the designer says that it doesn't have the permission to specific folders, which makes no sense to me.

Previously I installed VS2012 on C: partition, which was NTFS and ran into the same issue. However, I solved it by assigning proper permission on destination folders. Yet this time, it doesn't work in that it has no option for permission and security on a FAT32 partition except "hidden" and "readonly". I have also tried other tricky ways like trying to link the IDE folder to a duplicate on a NTFS partition, but haven't found the solution yet.

Is there anyone out there who knows any workaround or runs into the same issue?

FYI, the exception thrown by VS designer:

```
System.Security.SecurityException
Designer could not be started because of a permissions issue on the drive to which it is installed. Please check the permissions of the folder before trying to start the designer.
```

Comment: A workaround? Convert your drive to NTFS.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten No luck, having tried the "convert" command and 3-rd party tools. If I were to convert the drive, then I guess I would have to backup it and format it, which were the last thing I want to do.

Comment: Install a second drive, format it NTFS, move all your source code to that drive, load project from there.

If you use virtualbox to run a windows VM and run visual studio on the VM you can also bypass this problem by formating your VirtualBox HDD's in NTFS.

However, I keep my code on Fat32 to bypass the NTFS File Path limit of 260 characters so my node js NPM stuff doesn't fail (Node Packaged Modules), e.g. compiling bootstrap.